# What are the common image/video file extensions for Android and IoS to be granted to user?

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, upload, file-extension, filepicker

I am writing a Flutter application that needs user to upload some image and video files. I use the following code for that:

```
              FilePickerResult? result =
                  await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                allowMultiple: false,
                allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
              );

              FilePickerResult? result =
                  await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                allowMultiple: false,
                allowedExtensions: ['mp4', 'avi'],
              );
```

But I don't know what type of files should I specify in `file_picker`'s `AllowedExtensions` property?

My concern is about the specific file extensions that may a device model uses to store images/videos?

How can I deal with this?
Is there an option for `file_picker` to say allow images/videos in any format?( Although I am not sure about this as well and maybe I should put some restriction about the file formats I go to save on S3 as my application uses S3 for storage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `type` parameter instead:

```
await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.video)
```

See the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker/latest/file_picker/FilePicker-class.html)